# Cannot autowire Spring bean in JUnit test class

Tags: java, spring, junit, hsqldb, embedded-database

I would like to try embedded database for testing my DAO objects in Spring application.

In application context I have this tag:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSourceEmbedded" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/embeddeddb/schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/embeddeddb/data.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

my JUnit test class needs to work with this bean:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
public class PartnerDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceEmbedded")
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSourceEmbedded;

@Test
public void testSavePartner() {

}

}
```

everything works ("dataSourceEmbedded" bean is created) but when I try to autowire them in PartnerDAOTest class Spring throws this exception:

> testSavePartner(sandbox.PartnerDAOTest):
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'sandbox.PartnerDAOTest': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: public
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase
>   sandbox.PartnerDAOTest.dataSourceEmbedded;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=dataSourceEmbedded)}

**What is wrong with my code?**

Comment: The stacktrace is explicit: *Error creating bean with name `sandbox.PartnerDAOTest`: **Injection of autowired dependencies failed**. Could not autowire field: `public org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase`*.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I can read the exception it but I am sure everything is ok (or I have no idea what is wrong), because bean is created...

Comment: Well, it is not, otherwise the injection would be right. What I'm saying is, the problem cannot be checked with the current information you've posted.

Comment: What another information do you need to check the problem?

Comment: Well, looks like your `dataSourceEmbedded` bean is not defined in your applicationContext.xml file or it is not well referenced there. You can check for it in the stacktrace message: *`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`: No qualifying bean of type [`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase`] found for dependency*

Comment: There is no bean of the type `EmbeddedDatabase` there is a `DataSource`. The `embedded-database` eventually creates a `DataSource` not an `EmbeddedDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

As @M.Deinum noticed in his comment:

> There is no bean of the type EmbeddedDatabase there is a DataSource.
>   The embedded-database eventually creates a DataSource not an
>   EmbeddedDatabase.